# Loop on colum names with R

Tags: r, loops, assign

I am working with a dataframe (called "dataEPM"), with several columns among which some do have incremented columns names (ke_1, ke_2, .., ke_8). 
For these columns, I want to obtain the number of rows complying with a condition (==3), and the result in a dataframe output. So I write a loop on the column names. 
Here the code:

```
output_nb <- matrix(ncol=2, nrow=8)

for (i in 1:8){
  text <- paste("ke_",i, sep="")
  nb_i <- nrow(dataEPM[dataEPM$text == "3",])
  print(nrow(dataEPM[dataEPM$text == "3",]))
  output_nb[i,1] <- i
  output_nb[i,2] <- nb_i
}

output_nb <- data.frame(output_nb)
```

With the print command, I can see that `nrow(dataEPM[dataEPM$text == "3",])` is always equal to 0, nut when I replace the column name (e.g. `nrow(dataEPM[dataEPM$ke_1 == "3",])`) it is not. So I assume that this way of writing the column name is not accepted here.

Coudl you please tell me how to fix that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work :

```
for (i in 1:8){
  text_ <- paste("ke_",i, sep="")
  nb_i <- nrow(dataEPM[dataEPM[,text_] == "3",])
  print(nrow(dataEPM[dataEPM[,text_] == "3",]))
}
```

Just use plain boolean filters. Please tell me if it works!

Comment: Thanks, this works without changing much the initial code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to a tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
#dataframe with many ke_# columns
dataEPM <- tibble(ke_1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), # 1 three
                  ke_2 = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 5), # 2 threes
                  ke_3 = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3), # 3 threes
                  ke_4 = c(1, 3, 3, 3, 3)) # 4 threes

dataEPM %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("ke"), "new_col") %>% #combine all ke_# columns into one col
  dplyr::filter(value == 3) %>% #filter for values ==3
  group_by(new_col) %>% #group by unique ke_#
  summarize(num = n()) #count # occurences in each group

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  new_col  nrow
  <chr>   <int>
1 ke_1        1
2 ke_2        2
3 ke_3        3
4 ke_4        4
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `colSums` on a logical `vector` in `base R`

```
stack(colSums(dataEPM == 3))[2:1]
#   ind values
#1 ke_1      1
#2 ke_2      2
#3 ke_3      3
#4 ke_4      4
```

#### data

```
dataEPM <- data.frame(ke_1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), # 1 three
                  ke_2 = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 5), # 2 threes
                  ke_3 = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3), # 3 threes
                  ke_4 = c(1, 3, 3, 3, 3)) # 4 threes
```